# Передача безопасного аргумента из одного фрагмента в другой

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

Использую safeargs. Есть активность и несколько фрагментов, при открытии приложения показывается **TitleFragment** и TextView с ресурсом-строкой. Если пользователь перейдёт в другой пункт меню (другой фрагмент), то у него появится возможность ввести имя, и после нажатия на кнопку он должен перейти в **TitleFragment**, где уже отобразится изменённый TextView (должно быть добавлено имя, которое ввёл пользователь). Но в таком случае приложения крашится при запуске (т.к. в TitleFragment нет тех самых аргументов). Как я понимаю, что нужно добавить проверку на то, есть ли аргументы, или нет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать данную проверку (если я правильно понимаю), или есть другой способ реализовать это?

P.S. скорее всего максимально простая реализация (возможно даже есть где-то на глубине гугла, но, наверное я не умею гуглить), но, к сожалению, не получается

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.app

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI
import com.example.app.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarToolbar.toolbar) // toolbar support for app

        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment) // Create "NavFragment" (Main Fragment for other fragments)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout) // Create "Back" button on toolbar on other fragments
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController) // Create "Burger" button for menu
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, drawerLayout)
    }
}
```

**TitleFragment.kt** (то, что показывается при открытии приложения, тут должно показываться имя пользователя, когда он его введёт)

```
package com.example.app

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.example.app.databinding.FragmentTitleBinding

class TitleFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentTitleBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_title, container, false
        )

        // как я понимаю, что в краше виноваты как раз эти строки, 
        // и, видимо, где-то тут надо поставить проверку на то,
        // есть ли аргументы (при откртытии приложения)
        // 
        // пока что тут стоит Toast, но, изначально было изменение TextView
        // binding.textView.text = "Welcome ${args.userName}"
        val args = TitleFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments())
        if (args.userName.trim().isNotEmpty())
            Toast.makeText(
                activity,
                "Welcome ${args.userName}",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

**AccountFragment.kt** (тут пользователь вводит имя)

```
package com.example.app

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import com.example.app.databinding.FragmentAccountBinding

const val NAME = "name"

class AccountFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentAccountBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_account, container, false
        )

        // save data when the application change it's state
        binding.apply {
            if (savedInstanceState != null)
                editTextTextPersonName.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(NAME).toString())
            okButton.setOnClickListener { checkName() }
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun checkName() {
        binding.apply {
            if (editTextTextPersonName.text.isEmpty())
                Toast.makeText(
                    activity,
                    "Please write your name",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    activity,
                    "Hi ${editTextTextPersonName.text}!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                val userName: String = editTextTextPersonName.text.toString()
                view?.findNavController()?.navigate(
                    AccountFragmentDirections.actionAccountFragmentToTitleFragment(userName))
            }
        }
    }

    // save data when the application change it's state
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putString(NAME, binding.editTextTextPersonName.text.toString())
    }
}
```

Граф навигации **navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/titleFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/titleFragment"
        android:name="com.example.app.TitleFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_titleFragment_to_settingsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/settingsFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_titleFragment_to_accountFragment"
            app:destination="@id/accountFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_titleFragment_to_aboutFragment"
            app:destination="@id/aboutFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="userName"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/accountFragment"
        android:name="com.example.app.AccountFragment"
        android:label="@string/your_account">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_accountFragment_to_titleFragment"
            app:destination="@id/titleFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/aboutFragment"
        android:name="com.example.app.AboutFragment"
        android:label="@string/about_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_about" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: Дефолтное значение для строки: `null`.  Вы можете задать любое другое в графе, либо проверять в коде  на `null`. Я плохо знаю котлин, наверное можно написать так: `if (args.userName?.trim().isNotEmpty())`, на java: `if (args.userName != null && args.userName.trim().isNotEmpty())`. Или использовать класс-помощник из SDK: [`TextUtils.isEmpty(CharSequence)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/text/TextUtils#isEmpty(kotlin.CharSequence))

Comment: @woesss спасибо за подсказку, решение оказалось довольно простым. Если добавить просто проверку, то возникнет ошибка "Too many arguments for public open fun...". Мне нужно было всего-лишь в gradle изменить версию плагина safeargs на kotlin, после чего проверка заработала так, как надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашёлся:

В граф навигации добавляем **default value "@null"**. В **gradle** меняем **androidx.navigation.safeargs** на **androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin**.

После добавляем проверку

```
package com.example.app

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.example.app.databinding.FragmentTitleBinding

class TitleFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentTitleBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_title, container, false
        )

        // та самая проверка
        val args = TitleFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments())
        if (args.userName?.trim()?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
            Toast.makeText(
                activity,
                "Welcome ${args.userName}",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
        return binding.root
    }
}
```